# MATLAB - How to retain trained neural network with new dataset

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have trained neural network and i want to improve performance of network by retain trained neural network with new dataset. can i do this with command line not GUI.

For example: I have 3 dataset for training, 
1.) input1 and target1 2.) input2 and target2 3.) input3 and target3

```
net=patternnet(20);
net=train(net,input1,target1);
```

After trained neural net with first dataset its performance is under expect so i want to improve trained neural net with dataset 2 and 3 by not change network structure. how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to train the NN with 3 datasets, why not to make one bigger dataset?

```
input = [dataset1; dataset2; dataset3];
target = [target1;target2;target3];
```

If you don't like this option, you can retrain network with matlab dedicated [Neural Network Fitting Tool](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/gs/fit-data-with-a-neural-network.html#f9-33554).

[image]

Comment: In my case, now i have 3 dataset for train neural network and in the feture i will have more dataset for train. So can i improve network with retrain by pass new dataset to train function and use trained network. For example, train(net,input4,output4)